# Django: Get status of subprocess (running/finished) initiated from one view and display it to another view

Tags: python, django, subprocess

I want to start a subprocess from a specific URL (say eg: 'localhost:8000/start').

The status of subprocess (ie., the subprocess is running or finished) should be shown on another URL (say eg: 'localhost:8000/status').

I already started the subprocess. But I am struggling to display the status in another URL.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you add how your `subprocess` initialization is working?

Comment: @Saharsh `out = Popen(['python', 'script.py'],shell=False,stdout=PIPE,universal_newlines=True)` This is how I initiated the subprocess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking OP's comment stating

> @Saharsh `out = Popen(['python', 'script.py'],shell=False,stdout=PIPE,universal_newlines=True)` This is how I initiated the subprocess.

You might want to check `Popen.poll()` method. This will return `None` if process is still running and return status otherwise (like `0`).

```
out = Popen(['python', 'script.py'],shell=False,stdout=PIPE,universal_newlines=True)
...

def process_finished(process):
    if process.poll()==None:
        return False
    return True
```

Check [Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) in documentation for more details.

Comment: could you please give explanation on how to call process_finished(process) from another view.

Comment: You can just import the view (where method is) and call the it. That shouldn't really be a problem here.

Comment: I did n't get you. Actually I am very new to django. As per your answer I need to poll the process from another function. I don't know how to pass the process to another function.